# nodevectors not returning all nodes

Tags: python, graph, word2vec, embedding

I'm trying to use `nodevector`'s `Node2Vec` class to get an embedding for my graph. I can't show the entire code, but basically this is what I'm doing:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import nodevectors

n2v = nodevectors.Node2Vec(n_components=128,
                           walklen=80,
                           epochs=3,
                           return_weight=1,
                           neighbor_weight=1,
                           threads=4)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'customer', 'item', edge_attr='weight', create_using=nx.Graph)
n2v.fit(G)
model = n2v.model
shape = model.ww.vectors.shape
```

I know `G` has all the nodes from my scope. Then, I fit the model, but `model.ww.vectors` has a number of rows smaller than my number of nodes.

I'm not successfully finding why do the number of nodes represented in my embedding by `model.ww.vectors` is lower than my actual number of nodes in `G`.

Does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Your non-default `epochs=3` can result in some nodes appearing only 3 times – but the inner `Word2Vec` model by default ignores tokens appearing fewer than 5 times. Upping to `epochs=5` may be a quick fix - but read on for the reasons & tradeoffs with various defaults.

--

If you're using the `nodevectors` package described [here](https://github.com/VHRanger/nodevectors), it seems to be built on Gensim's `Word2Vec` – which uses a default `min_count=5`.

That means any tokens – in this case, nodes – which appear fewer than 5 times are ignored. Especially in the natural-language contexts where `Word2Vec` was pioneered, discarding such rare words entirely usually has multiple benefits:

- from only a few idiosyncratic examples, such rare words themselves get peculiar vectors less-likely to generalize to downstream uses (other texts)
- compared to other frequent words, each gets very little training effort overall, & thus provides only a little pushback on shared model weights (based on their peculiar examples) - so the vectors are weaker & retain more arbitrary influence from random-initialization & relative positioning in the corpus. (More-frequent words provide more varied, numerous examples to extract their unique meaning.)
- because of the Zipfian distribution of word-frequencies in natural language, there are *a lot* of such low-frequency words – often even typos – and altogether they take up a lot of the model's memory & training-time. But they *don't* individually get very good vectors, or have generalizable beneficial influences on the shared model. So they wind up serving a lot like noise that weakens other vectors for more-frequent words, as well.

So typically in `Word2Vec`, discarding rare words only gives up low-value vectors while simultaneously speeding training, shrinking memory requirements, & improving the quality of the remaining vectors: a big win.

Although the distribution of node-names in graph random-walks may be very different from natural-language word-frequencies, some of the same concerns still apply for nodes that appear rarely. On the other hand, if a node truly only appears at the end of a long chain of nodes, every walk to or from it will include the exact same neighbors - and maybe extra appearances in more walks would add no new variety-of-information (at least within the inner `Word2Vec` `window` of analysis).

You may be able to confirm if the default `min_count` is your issue by using the `Node2Vec` `keep_walks` parameter to store the generated walks, then checking: are exactly the nodes that are 'missing' appearing fewer than `min_count` times in the walks?

If so, a few options may be:

- override `min_count` using the `Node2Vec` `w2vparams` option to something like `min_count=1`. As noted above, this is always a bad idea in traditional natural-language `Word2Vec` - but maybe it's not so bad in a graph application, where for rare/outer-edge nodes one walk is enough, and then at least you have whatever strange/noisy vector results from that minimal training.
- try to influence the walks to ensure all nodes appear enough times. I suppose some values of the `Node2Vec` `walklen`, `return_weight`, & `neighbor_weight` could improve coverage - but I don't think they could guarantee all nodes appear in at least N (say, 5, to match the default `min_count`) different walks. But it looks like the `Node2Vec` `epochs` parameter controls how many time *every* node is used as a starting point – so `epochs=5` would guarantee every node appears at least 5 times, as the start of 5 separate walks. (Notably: the `Node2Vec` default is `epochs=20` - which would never trigger a bad interaction with the internal `Word2Vec` `min_count=5`. But setting your non-default `epochs=3` risks leaving some nodes with only 3 appearances.)

Comment: Thanks! Really helped me a lot :)