# How to obtain Node2Vec vectors all of the nodes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec

I have tried `nodevectors` , fastnode2vec. But I cannot get vectors of all nodes. Why?
e.g.

The code is

```
from fastnode2vec import Node2Vec

graph = Graph(_lst, directed=True, weighted=True)

model = Node2Vec(_graph, dim=300, walk_length=100, context=10, p=2.0, q=0.5, workers=-1)

model.train(epochs=epochs)
```

I have 10,000 nodes. When I check:

```
model.index_to_key
```

there are only 502 nodes.
Why is that?
How to set parameters so I can get the vectors of all nodes?

Comment: Please use some openly available data to post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your settings are not generating enough appearances of all nodes to meet other requirements for inclusion, such as the `min_count=5` used by the related `Word2Vec` superclass to discard tokens with too few example usages to model well.

See this other related answer for related considerations & possible fixes (though in the context of the `nodevectors` package rather than the `fastnode2vec` package you're using):

[nodevectors not returning all nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227156/nodevectors-not-returning-all-nodes/71227734#71227734)

If that doesn't help resolve your issue, you should include more details about your graph - such as demonstrating via displayed output that it really has 10,000 nodes, & they're all sufficiently conneted, & that the random-walks generated by your node2vec library sufficiently revisit all of them for the training purposes.